# WCF Custom Class Arguments

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF method which takes an argument that is a custom class, say,

```
void MyWCFMethod(MyCustomClass MethodArgument)
```

In the above, MyCustomClass has a number of constructor overloads.  The service has a reference to the class but not the client.  I want to allow the client to use the other overloads but the default constructor is the only one that seems to be allowed.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this, but I think it is important to know why the Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) do not expose logic over the service reference.

The WSDL\XSD metadata that is used in order to generate the client proxy to access the WCF Service only describes the web service by the operations exposed and the datatypes exchanged.

Specifically, XSD only describes the **structure** of your DTOs and not the logic - that is why there is only the default constructor and public properties/fields available on the client proxy.

So the solution is to put all of your custom classes exchanged between the client and service in a separate shared library. This way both sides of the wire have access to the additional logic (like your parameterized constructors) that you could not obtain via WSDL\XSD.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems quite important to my boss that the service and client don't share any code.  Thanks

Comment: In scenarios where you don't necessarily own both ends of the wire and/or it's not .NET to .NET (or you don't want to pigeonhole client developers to .NET), then this approach is not feasible. It's nice to do this for those scenarios where you can guarantee such an environment as it opens up opportunities such as this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess - no!

As I understand MyCustomClass is data contract and marked by [DataContract] attribute.
So WCF runtime will use [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (by default) to deserialize data from received message to the instance of object.

So where can DataContractSerializer get additional parameters for your specific constructors?
Instance of data contract must have public parameter-less constructor to be instantiated.
But maybe you can write own serializer (but keep in mind that DataContractSerializer cannot be inherited)... and provide additional data to constructor. But if you can get that information somewhere just do it in public parameter-less constructor of your data contract.

So I guess you are doing something wrong. Try to specify what is the goal to pass data in constructor in your case. Maybe your app can use some another solution.

Comment: The class does not have a DataContract on it, maybe it should.  It appears the client gets whatever information it has through the service reference.

Comment: You can also explicitly create a data contract by using DataContractAttribute and DataMemberAttribute attributes. This is normally done by applying the DataContractAttribute attribute to the type. This attribute can be applied to classes, structures, and enumerations. The DataMemberAttribute attribute must then be applied to each member of the data contract type to indicate that it is a data member. I think it is data contract independently of explicit declaration. And it does not impact things related to your question.